# Oracle database how to set permanent value function to column?

Tags: oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper, netbeans-7

I am using Oracle 11g express and SqlDeveloper 4.0.3.In my database i have a table called TABLE1 like this:

```
   ID   A    B   C
   1    3    2   null
   2    1    2   null
```

I also have a java program that inserts values on the table the ID,A,B.
So i want the database to remember like a function to add column A and B and set it to C and not doing it manually like this on the Query on Developer :
UPDATE TABLE1 SET C=A+B WHERE C IS NULL;

How can it be done?

Comment: It sounds like you want column C to be a virtual column rather than a physical column.  Can you drop the existing physical column C and create a new virtual column?  If you want a physical column, you'd want to create a trigger that computes the C value.

Comment: I don't know how to write the trigger code for my example.

Comment: Do you care whether you end up with a physical column or a virtual column?  My guess is that you want a virtual column.  I'm happy to show you how if you're happy to drop the existing physical column.  If you need that physical column, I'm happy to help you with a trigger.  I don't know what your constraints are, though, so I don't know whether either of these options is acceptable to you.

Comment: I just want C column to be like a calculated field and not doing it manually like  Update above.Also to store the values in C column and not lose them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess is that you want to drop the existing physical column C and to create a new virtual column C

```
ALTER TABLE table1
  DROP COLUMN c;

ALTER TABLE table1
  ADD c GENERATED ALWAYS AS (a+b);
```

Comment: Yes that's it.Thank you very much.